# How to rotate a list by moving each element in the list n times to the right using java linkedlist

Tags: java

Example :
"ID_A01"->"ID_A02"->"ID_A03"->"ID_A04"->"ID_A05"->"ID_A06"->null

and n=2

You should return the following list:
"ID_A05"->"ID_A06"->"ID_A01"->"ID_A02"->"ID_A03"->"ID_A04"->null

Comment: show us what you have tried.

Comment: Please share what you have tried. Read this javadoc on the rotate method https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html

Answer (score 1):

You could make use of `removeLast` and `addFirst` function implemented in LinkedList class, and loop over it n times.

```
import java.util.*;

public class HelloWorld{

    public static void main(String []args){
       LinkedList<String> linkedlist = new LinkedList<String>();

       linkedlist.add("Item1");
       linkedlist.add("Item2");
       linkedlist.add("Item3");
       linkedlist.add("Item4");
       linkedlist.add("Item5");

       System.out.println("Linked List Content: " +linkedlist);
       rotate(linkedlist, 2);
       System.out.println("Linked List Content: " +linkedlist);
    }

    public static void rotate(LinkedList linkedlist, int n) {
       for (int i=0; i<n; i++) {
           Object item = linkedlist.removeLast();
           linkedlist.addFirst(item);
       }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why write your own rotate method instead of using the one in Collections class?

Answer (score 0):

[image]You should attach the first node and the last node of the LinkedList.
put the address of the first node in the last node instead of null

Comment: Be careful to keep the address of the first and last node for easy insertion.